# Как установить плагин для RoR в RubyMine?

Tags: github, ide, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Точнее, как выполнить эту строку из руководства?

```
$ script/plugin install git://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git
```

Или как это можно сделать не в IDE, если так будет удобнее?

Comment: «Плагины» в Ruby называются *гемами*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в `Gemfile`:

```
gem "restful-authentication"
```

И RubyMine сама выполнит `bundle install`

Answer (score 2):

Руководство вероятно для 2.3-style rails.

1. Вкладка Tools | Run Rails Script
2. Клац на "..."  и выбираем установку плагина
3. Добавьте специфичные аргументы если требуется

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Иногда возникает потребность установки двух версий одного и того же гема, для этого открываешь терминал (вкладка обычно находится в левом нижнем углу RubyMine) и устанавливаешь командами:

```
gem install some_gem -v 1.0
gem install some_gem -v 2.0
```

ну и там же проверяешь командой:

```
gem list some_gem
```

на выходе будет что-то типа

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
  some_gem (1.0, 2.0)
```